# How can I place an image inside a DataGridCell when a validation error occurs?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

Here is what my DataGrid xaml markup looks like currently and the image doesn't show up at all even if an validation error happens. The only validation errors I have in place are if there is data entered in the field (field is required).

```
<DataGrid RowValidationErrorTemplate="{x:Null}" Name="dataGridInstitution" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=OrgIDs, Mode=TwoWay}" CanUserDeleteRows="True" CanUserAddRows="True" AddingNewItem="DataGrid_AddingNewInstitution" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="300" Width="1170" CanUserResizeColumns="False" >
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="CellErrorStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
            <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate" >
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <DataGridCell>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}" />
                                <Image Source="icons/status_error.png" Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataGridCell>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn     Header="Institution ID" Binding="{Binding Institution, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True }"       Width="80"  CellStyle="{StaticResource CellErrorStyle}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn     Header="Org ID"         Binding="{Binding value, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True }"             Width="50"  CellStyle="{StaticResource CellErrorStyle}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn     Header="Data Source"    Binding="{Binding Datasource, Mode=TwoWay }"                                    Width="150" />
        <DataGridTextColumn     Header="User Code"      Binding="{Binding Security.UserCode, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True }" Width="70"  CellStyle="{StaticResource CellErrorStyle}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn     Header="Password"       Binding="{Binding Security.Password, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True }" Width="75"  CellStyle="{StaticResource CellErrorStyle}" />
        <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Image Web Service Location"           ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Specifications}, Path=ImageWebServices, Mode=TwoWay}"           SelectedItemBinding="{Binding ServerLocation, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" Width="325" CellStyle="{StaticResource CellErrorStyle}" />
        <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Image Streaming Web Service Location" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Specifications}, Path=ImageStreamingWebServices, Mode=TwoWay }" SelectedItemBinding="{Binding StreamingServerLocation}"                    Width="325" />
        <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Trace Level"                          ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource tracingEnum}}"                                                  SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Tracing.Level, Mode=TwoWay}"                 Width="*" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not do this: `RowValidationErrorTemplate="{x:Null}"`

Instead you should set it's value to a the desires looks you want your control to have when it has validation errors. Like this:

```
<DataGrid Name="dataGridInstitution" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=OrgIDs, Mode=TwoWay}" CanUserDeleteRows="True" CanUserAddRows="True" AddingNewItem="DataGrid_AddingNewInstitution" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="300" Width="1170" CanUserResizeColumns="False" >
    <DataGrid.RowValidationErrorTemplate>
      <ControlTemplate>
        <Grid Margin="0,-2,0,-2"
          <Image Source="myImage.jpg" />
        </Grid>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </DataGrid.RowValidationErrorTemplate>
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="CellErrorStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
            <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate" >
                <Setter.Value>
                   <ControlTemplate>
                       <DataGridCell>
                          <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                              <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}" />
                              <Image Source="icons/status_error.png" Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
                          </StackPanel>
                       </DataGridCell>
                   </ControlTemplate>
               </Setter.Value>
             </Setter>
          </Style>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
       <DataGridTextColumn     Header="Institution ID" Binding="{Binding Institution, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True }"       Width="80"  CellStyle="{StaticResource CellErrorStyle}" />
       <DataGridTextColumn     Header="Org ID"         Binding="{Binding value, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True }"             Width="50"  CellStyle="{StaticResource CellErrorStyle}" />
       <DataGridTextColumn     Header="Data Source"    Binding="{Binding Datasource, Mode=TwoWay }"                                    Width="150" />
       <DataGridTextColumn     Header="User Code"      Binding="{Binding Security.UserCode, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True }" Width="70"  CellStyle="{StaticResource CellErrorStyle}" />
       <DataGridTextColumn     Header="Password"       Binding="{Binding Security.Password, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True }" Width="75"  CellStyle="{StaticResource CellErrorStyle}" />
       <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Image Web Service Location"           ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Specifications}, Path=ImageWebServices, Mode=TwoWay}"           SelectedItemBinding="{Binding ServerLocation, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" Width="325" CellStyle="{StaticResource CellErrorStyle}" />
       <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Image Streaming Web Service Location" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Specifications}, Path=ImageStreamingWebServices, Mode=TwoWay }" SelectedItemBinding="{Binding StreamingServerLocation}"                    Width="325" />
       <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Trace Level"                          ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource tracingEnum}}"                                                  SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Tracing.Level, Mode=TwoWay}"                 Width="*" />
  </DataGrid.Columns>
```

**-- Edit --**

The previous method is to have validation error for each row which is somewhat standard and more efficient. But, if you want validation cell by cell then you need to use styles like this:

```
<Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
    <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate" Value="{x:Null}"/>
</Style>
<Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate >
            <!--You do your styling here-->
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

For more information there is this great article [here](http://blogs.u2u.be/diederik/post/2009/09/30/Validation-in-a-WPF-DataGrid.aspx)

Comment: This accomplishes adding an icon to the start of the row but 2 concerns.
1. I want the icon to show up in the DataGridCell where the error happened (currently just showing a red border in the cell).
2. The icon from the error at the start of the row doesn't get cleared once I fix the errors in the row.

Comment: I recommend don't go down that road unless you really have to. But I edited the answer anyway, hope it helps.

Comment: This makes sense to have the icon on the row rather than the cell, although I haven't found a way to clear the icon after the errors have been resolved.

Comment: It should clear when you navigate away from the culprit cell with a valid data (i.e. go to a new row)